# Migrate Ubuntu to smaller partition

Tags: partitioning, migration

I have a 320 GB HDD, and I want to migrate my Ubuntu system to a 60 GB SSD I bought.

I have an `ext4` root partition and a swap partition. The root partition has 314 GB, but my files take up 50 GB, the rest is free space, so my partition is larger than the SSD, but my files can fit in it.

I have already partitioned the SSD with a 54 GB `ext4` partition and a swap partition, now I only need to move my files to it.

What is the best approach here - using `cp`, `dd`, `gparted`, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

While the cp -ax command reference will work, I believe in clean installs. I also believe in entire bootable system on every hard drive and data partitions on other hard drives.

So with my 60GB SSD, I created two / (root) partitions of about 27GB, one current working install and one for testing. My root includes my /home but none of the data folders and even some of the hidden data folder like Firefox & Thunderbird. All data in then in data partitions on my hard drive and linked back to /home so it looks like normal structure of folders.
My / on my working install used 9GB and 2GB of the 9 is /home. And most of the 2GB in /home is .wine which is the only data I have not moved to a data partition.